# disable space in edittext in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm  trying to prevent a space/enter pressing into edittext. 
I found code for preventing a space but it`s not working for me. please tell me what is the problem and how I can fix it

```js
package com.example.apc.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        TextView inputView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String result = s.toString().replaceAll(" ", "");
        if (!s.toString().equals(result)) {
            inputView.setText(result);
            inputView.setSelection(result.length());
        }
    }
}
```

Error:(21, 21) error: cannot find symbol method setSelection(int)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>   Error:(15, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict user for entering input, you may use android:digits="0123456789." in the xml file where you have created the edittext view. You may type any type of allowed character to digits attribute. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
package com.example.apc.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 TextView inputView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
inputView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  
  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   
  }
  
  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
    int arg3) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   
  }
  
  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     String result = s.toString().replaceAll(" ", "");
        if (!s.toString().equals(result)) {
            inputView.setText(result);
            inputView.setSelection(result.length());
        }
  }
 });



    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well what you have in question is a `TextView` not a `EditText`,

back to the problem, I believe you don't want, Is that user press a space and tries to save it.

if you try to prevent user from typing spaces you will make the code complicated and that is not required here.

what you can do is check if the `text` entered by the user is valid text or not, and if it is only space you see in text it can be trimmed and notify that to user to enter a valid text in the `EditText`

```
EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.one_editText);
String text_string = editText.getText().toString();

if (!isValidText(text_string)) {
     Toast.makeToast(context, "Kindly Provide a valid Customer Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
 }
```

all you have to check is the text is valid or not, internally you can have your own implementation

```
public boolean isValidText(String text) {
    if (text == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (text.trim().contentEquals("")) {
        return false;
    }

    if (text.trim().length() < 1) {
        return false;
    }

    if (text.trim().toLowerCase().contentEquals("null")) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks but this code doesn`t work
first I will that i think you mean to write one of the lines like that
    EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
i`ve got some problem with those lines:
1)    if (!isValidText(text_string)) {
2)       return;

Error:(20, 5) error: illegal start of type
Error:(20, 9) error: illegal start of type
Error:(20, 10) error: ')' expected
Error:(20, 33) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(20, 34) error: illegal start of type
and nore..
sry but i can`t paste here the hole code becuase it`s too long for comment

Comment: @bill, i have tested the code check this out https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/activities/list/first/ExampleOneActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

Use in xml  as -

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/nombre"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    android:hint="hint text*"
     />
```

you can add any digit in it